# mysql selects for perf tuning

Tags: mysql

Any idea why cli.clitype and c.cli is not being picked even if I use/force index as hint in sql. Its giving me the output in 4 secs to fetch 1634 only for the below query. I'm using 5.5.25.log Please suggest.

```
mysql> explain SELECT   DATE(sr.`date`),   v.company_name,   c.cli,   COUNT(*),   c.charge,   SUM(c.`charge`) FROM subscriptionrequest AS sr, cli AS c ,   vendor AS v WHERE sr.cli = c.cli     AND sr.secretkey = v.secretkey     AND sr.`date` BETWEEN'2012-03-12 00:00:00' AND '2012-10-13 00:00:00' and c.clitype = 'chargemo' GROUP BY DATE(sr.`date`), sr.secretkey,c.cli;
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                 | key            | key_len | ref                        | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL  | idx_cli                                       | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                       |  115 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sr    | ref  | idx_subreq_key,idx_subreq_cli,idx_subreq_date | idx_subreq_cli | 53      | crystal_du_sm.c.cli        |  869 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | ref  | secretkey_idx                                 | secretkey_idx  | 52      | crystal_du_sm.sr.secretkey |    1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> show indexes from cli;
+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------     ----+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation |      Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
 +-------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+--------    -----+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| cli   |          0 | PRIMARY      |            1 | idcli       | A         |             115 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cli   |          1 | idx_cli      |            1 | cli         | A         |         115 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cli   |          1 | cli_type_idx |            1 | clitype     | A         |         115 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+---------     ----+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)    


mysql> show create table cli;

| cli   | CREATE TABLE `cli` (
`idcli` bigint(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`cli` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`type` enum('SDMF','MDMF') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SDMF',
`priority` enum('realtime','high','normal','low','ignore') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'normal',
`status` enum('active','inactive','suspended','deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`description` text,
`charge` float DEFAULT '0',
`clitype` enum('chargemo','freemo') DEFAULT 'freemo',
PRIMARY KEY (`idcli`),
KEY `idx_cli` (`cli`),
KEY `cli_type_idx` (`clitype`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=117 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table vendor;
| vendor | CREATE TABLE `vendor` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`company_name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
`phone_no` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
`status` enum('active','inactive','suspended','deleted') DEFAULT 'active',
`mo` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
`mt` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
`used_mo` bigint(255) DEFAULT '0',
`used_mt` bigint(255) DEFAULT '0',
`start_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`end_time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`secretkey` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`callback_url` text,
`payment_callback_url` text,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`userid` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `secretkey_idx` (`secretkey`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

| subscriptionrequest | CREATE TABLE `subscriptionrequest` (
`id` bigint(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ipaddress` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
`message` text,
`msisdn` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`mode` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`cli` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`transactionid` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`secretkey` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`error_code` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`success` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`status` enum('waiting','processing','completed','moexceeds','reject') DEFAULT     'waiting',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_subreq_key` (`secretkey`),
KEY `idx_subreq_status` (`status`),
KEY `idx_subreq_transid` (`transactionid`),
KEY `idx_subreq_cli` (`cli`),
KEY `idx_subreq_date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1594161 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

FOR SETSUNA  ---

```
mysql> explain SELECT DATE(sr.`date`) AS sr_date, v.company_name, c.cli, 
->   COUNT(*) AS cnt, c.charge, 
->   SUM(c.`charge`) AS charge_sum 
->   FROM 
->   subscriptionrequest AS sr 
->   JOIN cli AS c ON sr.cli = c.cli     
->   JOIN vendor AS v ON sr.secretkey = v.secretkey
->   WHERE 
->   sr.`date` >= '2012-03-12' AND sr.`date` <= '2012-10-13' 
->   AND c.clitype = 'chargemo' 
->   GROUP BY DATE(sr.`date`), sr.secretkey, c.cli;
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------+----------------+---------     +---------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys               | key            | key_len     | ref                       | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------+----------------+---------  +---------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | ALL  | secretkey_idx               | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                      |     9 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sr    | ref  | idx_subreq_key,cli_date_idx | idx_subreq_key | 103     | crystal_du_sm.v.secretkey | 88746 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref  | idx_cli,cli_type_idx        | idx_cli        | 258         | crystal_du_sm.sr.cli      |     1 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------+----------------+---------   +---------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

--- 23/8/2012 ---

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------+------------  -----+---------+----------------------------+-------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                         | key               | key_len | ref                        | rows  | Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+----------------------------+-------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | ALL  | secretkey_idx                         | NULL            | NULL    | NULL                       |     9 | Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sr    | ref  | idx_subreq_key,idx_date_cli_secretkey | idx_subreq_key  | 103     | crystal_du_sm.v.secretkey  | 88608 | Using where     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref  | idx_cli_clitype                       | idx_cli_clitype     | 260     | crystal_du_sm.sr.cli,const |     1 | Using where     |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------+----------------   -+---------+----------------------------+-------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Have you tried ORDER BY NULL to suppress the implicit sorting from grouping? Also use JOIN instead of multiple table SELECT.

Comment: It would be better too if you could provide the structure of the tables involved in the query.

Comment: @setsuna - added to the above question now.

Comment: `BIGINT(255)` - what's that for? Also, theta-style joins might lead to  undesirable behaviour, better rewrite that query using regular `ON` joins and test the query again.

Comment: using ON join it gave the result in  8secs

Answer (score 1):

A couple of general remarks:

- Avoid using reserved keywords as column names (*subscriptionrequest.date*)
- Use aliases on field names especially when using functions

I think this version is more readable

```
  SELECT DATE(sr.`date`) AS sr_date, v.company_name, c.cli, 
  COUNT(*) AS cnt, c.charge, 
  SUM(c.`charge`) AS charge_sum 
  FROM 
  subscriptionrequest AS sr 
  JOIN cli AS c ON sr.cli = c.cli     
  JOIN vendor AS v ON sr.secretkey = v.secretkey
  WHERE 
  sr.`date` >= '2012-03-12' AND sr.`date` <= '2012-10-13' 
  AND c.clitype = 'chargemo' 
  GROUP BY DATE(sr.`date`), sr.secretkey, c.cli;
```

You will probably need to modify the *subscriptionrequest* table:

```
ALTER TABLE subscriptionrequest DROP INDEX `idx_subreq_cli` , DROP INDEX 
`idx_subreq_date`, ADD INDEX `cli_date` (`date`,`cli`);
```

This will help fetching the proper subset of records based on the date field thus diminishing the number of returned records from the *subscriptionrequest* table.

**Edit #1**

Schema Modifications & (Slight) Query Optimization:

```
ALTER TABLE subscriptionrequest DROP INDEX `cli_date`, 
ADD INDEX `idx_date_cli_secretkey` (`date`,`secretkey`,`cli`);

ALTER TABLE `cli` DROP INDEX idx_cli, DROP INDEX cli_type_idx, 
ADD INDEX `idx_cli_clitype` (cli,clitype);

EXPLAIN  SELECT DATE(sr.`date`) AS sr_date, v.company_name, c.cli, 
COUNT(*) AS cnt, c.charge, SUM(c.`charge`) AS charge_sum    
FROM    subscriptionrequest AS sr JOIN 
cli AS c ON sr.cli = c.cli JOIN vendor AS v ON sr.secretkey = v.secretkey     
WHERE  sr.`date` >= '2012-03-12' AND sr.`date` <= '2012-10-13' 
AND c.clitype = 'chargemo' GROUP BY DATE(sr.`date`), sr.secretkey, c.cli 
ORDER BY NULL\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: sr
         type: index
possible_keys: idx_subreq_key,idx_date_cli_secretkey
          key: idx_date_cli_secretkey
      key_len: 160
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using temporary
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_cli_clitype
          key: idx_cli_clitype
      key_len: 260
          ref: so_12055859.sr.cli,const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: v
         type: ref
possible_keys: secretkey_idx
          key: secretkey_idx
      key_len: 52
          ref: so_12055859.sr.secretkey
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: -its giving output in 8secs now. after dropping and recreating index on date,cli. - Below is the explain plan and using the query with JOIN.

Comment: | id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys               | key            | key_len | ref                       | rows  | Extra                           
|  1 | SIMPLE      | v     | ALL  | secretkey_idx               | NULL           | NULL    | NULL               |     9 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE| sr | ref  | idx_subreq_key,cli_date_idx | idx_subreq_key | 103| crystal_du_sm.v.secretkey | 88746 | Using where                     |
|1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref  | idx_cli,cli_type_idx        | idx_cli | 258     | crystal_du_sm.sr.cli      |     1 | Using where

Comment: Could you please add the query plan as an edit in your question? It lacks the formatting as a comment.

Comment: @mannoj I just reviewed my answer. Check it out and tell me if it works!

Comment: 2779 rows in set (9.14 sec) -> output time and fetched rows Returned - I see that it takes 30 milli secs for joins and picking the indexes from others whereas when it goes date range table scan on subscriptionrequest table which is having 1594082 rows, whereas when I truncate some data from the table and do search for left out data of about 338088 rows it gives output in 1 sec for 140 rows.

Comment: How many records are there for this date range? Try running SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subscriptionrequest sr WHERE 
  sr.`date` >= '2012-03-12' AND sr.`date` <= '2012-10-13' . Also could you replace the query plan in your question with the new one? I am not really sure that this can be further optimized, plus a table with 1.5M records is not considered large. Perhaps I am missing something here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15705/discussion-between-mannoj-and-setsuna)

Comment: 1472913 - for the count(*) between date ranges.
pls see the explain plan in question...